# Valid parameters for New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to assign a **group** to the Azure application from PowerShell. For that, I activated the Azure AD Premium P2 license free trial recently as it is a prerequisite.

**Command**:

```
New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId groupid -Id appid -PrincipalId groupid -ResourceId appid
```

**Error:**

```
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing NewUserAppRoleAssignment 
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource 'xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
RequestId: 85bd8a07-47b8-42d1-9ea8-4966b309350b
DateTimeStamp: Thu, 11 Aug 2022 07:46:33 GMT
HttpStatusCode: NotFound
HttpStatusDescription: Not Found
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewUserAppRoleAssignment
```

I'm guessing something is wrong with my parameters but the below document does not specify any working example for reference. It just mentioned value to be string:

[New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadgroupapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0)

I tried with both appid and objectid of enterprise and normal app. But still getting the same error:( Anyone tried this and made it work?

Comment: The `appid` is a **string** yes?

Comment: Yes, I gave `appid` in this "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx" format

Comment: Instead of `appid`, you need to pass `appRoleId` for **-Id** parameter in the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

```
New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId 7b344d79-xxxxx -Id 31dfe12d-xxxxxx -PrincipalId 7b344d79-xxxxxx -ResourceId 31dfe12d-xxxxxx
```

*I ran the above command giving same parameters as you and got the same error as below:*

[image]

***To resolve the error, you need to pass parameters as below:***

- ObjectId - Your group object ID
- PrincipalId - Your group object ID
- ResourceId  - Your Enterprise App's object ID
- Id - AppRole ID

***To make it simple, try using below PowerShell Script:***

```
$groupid = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
$app_name = "your_app_name"
$app_role_name = "your_app_role"

$group = Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId $groupid
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq 'your_app_role' }

New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -PrincipalId $group.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
```

**Output:**

[image]

***When I ran the above script, group is assigned to the app successfully like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**
[Assign users and groups  | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal)

Comment: Thanks @SrideviM , with the given script I assigned the group successfully!